# What’s the font in the Panda Vape logo?

Tags: logo, font-identification

[image]

I have a logo which is using the same typeface as the Panda Vape logo. I found it while searching the Logo on Google. Can you please help me identify it, so I can use it in my logo design? I have tried searching on WhatTheFont, What Font Is, and Find my Font, but I couldn’t find the exact font.

Answer (score 3):

#### It's called Planet Kosmos.

[image]

http://www.dafont.com/planet-kosmos.font

It was on the first page of the "sci-fi" category on DaFont.

Note it is only free for noncommercial use. There is a link to [the authors website](http://www.planet.dk/fonts/) from DafFont, but no clear way to purchase a license.

Comment: Kaliber BRK is a somewhat similar font that is free for commercial use  http://www.1001fonts.com/kaliber-brk-font.html